# Doorkeeper separate resource server from the authorization server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

I am building an ouath 2.0 system in ruby on rails using [Doorkeeper](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper).
My resource server is protected with doorkeeper_for method and  is separate from the authorization server, and i am using the implicit grant flow.
So i get the access token from the auth server and then make a request to the resource server in this way: localhsot:3000/pages?access_token=XXXX but when the resource server read the access token it try to looks for the token in its own database and not in the authentication server database so i get a 401 Unautorized error. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a database connection to the authorization server, and in a `MyApp::Application.config.to_prepare` block instruct the relevant `doorkeeper` models to connect via those credentials.

See https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper/issues/266#issuecomment-26800252.

Comment: Is this truly separating Authorization Server from Resource Server or just distributing authorization across resource servers?  If I'm understanding correctly, you're telling the Resource server to use the Auth Server database?  Or am I misunderstanding.